# Runtime exception at 0x00400010: address out of range 0x00000000

Tags: assembly, mips

My MIPS implementation, looping over strings:
I keep getting:

- Exception occurred at PC=0x10010010
- Bad address in text read: 0x10010010

NOT sure of why this is happening, I tried debugging and stepping. If, anyone knows exactly what's wrong in this code, please answer. I am continuing to try to debug..

YES, this is the ENTIRE code, feel free to run it in QtSpim.

```
    .data

   STR_str:
    .asciiz "Cow, Bird, Beer"

   .text

   loop_over_strings:

    addi    $sp, $sp, -4        
    sw  $ra, 0($sp) 
    sw  $a1, 8($sp)

     loop:
    
      sw $a0, 4($sp)        
      lb $t0, 0($a0)            
      beqz $t0, end_loop
    
    jalr $a1                
    
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    lw $a1, 8($sp)
    addi $a0, $a0, 1        
    j loop  

   end_loop:
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)         
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4     

    jr  $ra


    .text
    .globl main

   main:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -4    # PUSH return address
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)
    
    la  $a0, STR_str
    la  $a1, ascii
    jal loop_over_strings
    
    lw  $ra, 0($sp) # POP return address
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4 
    
    jr  $ra
```

Comment: Do you have a C version of this to compare with?  I'm having trouble understanding what you might be trying to do.

Comment: @ErikEidt, posted C code as per your request. Thanks.

Comment: This C code is not really the same thing.  Names are different, parameters are different, there's no function pointers in the C version, why is there one in the assembly version?  `loop_over_strings` takes 2 parameters in assembly, but I see no two parameter function in the C (nor one named `loop_over_strings`).

Comment: @ErikEidt, that's because, I wrote a function that's called from the main in MIPS, to separate the code. Maybe, I should've done that in C too. Basically, I am trying to loop through all chars, one after the other, and print the char and it's original ASCII code. I am sending to the subroutine `ascii` function in the MIPS.

Comment: Make the C code match what you're trying to do *exactly*, for your own clarity (and ours too).  Working C (or pseudo) code is, I would argue, essential for clarity and to get your algorithm working, so then follow it exactly in assembly -- don't make optimizations or alterations in going to assembly.  If you want optimizations or other changes, do them in C first, make sure they work, then translate the C literally.  A proper separation of working algorithm and its assembly translation makes assembly programming much easier.

Comment: @ErikEidt, dude, I am not in for optimization of code, if it was for that, I wouldn't be here. My concern is an exception I keep on getting, which is annoying, and I cannot understand why or where. The entire MIPS assembly code is available above. Feel free to run it in QtSpim and let me know, what you see that I don't.

Comment: The assembly code is vastly different from the C code, it has many changes, usage of function pointers, three function instead of two.  Try to go for some algorithmic clarity in C first.

Comment: @ErikEidt, did you see my last edit? The assembly code is obviously working. It prints out successfully, but, it throws an exception at the end.

Comment: Sorry you're having problems, and hope you figure it out.  Very hard for us to help if you can communicate only an idea of the intention of the code but not the actual algorithm you're attempting.  Little details matter in assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `loop_over_strings`, you're allocating 4 bytes of stack space but its using 12, so something is going to be overwritten — that something being overwritten is probably someone else's stacked return address.

Answer (score -1):

You've placed some of your code in the `.data` section. It needs to be in the `.text` section.

Comment: Yes, but, I solved that. **However, I keep getting the issue. The problem remains**. If you have `QtSpim` you can run the code and see what's wrong with it, what am I missing.

Comment: You've edited your question so that the title no longer matches the description. I answered the original question. Separate problems should be handled as separate questions. Although the problem that you now mention in the title should be easy enough for you to solve yourself since you know te exact instruction where the exception occurs.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't change the title. I added, `.text` so, that people wouldn't get confused. No, I don't know where the problem is in my code, that's why I posted here. There's no reason for you **Michael** to behave *DISRESPECTFULLY* here around.

Comment: @JohnSmith The [editing history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69505074/revisions) does not seem to agree with your claim, showing that you changed the title from "Exception occurred at PC=0x1001000c, Bad address in text read: 0x1001000f" to "Runtime exception at 0x00400010: address out of range 0x00000000".

Comment: It's the same Error. I updated it, after **MARS Mips Assembler Runtime Simulator** showed me that error, whereas, the previous error came from **QtSpim**.